# Makefile.unix error unrecognized command line option “-std=c++03”

Tags: c++, gcc

When I run `make -f makefile.unix` it gives me an error like this:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++03"
```

Then I tried the following command: `make -f makefile.unix CXXFLAGS="-std=c++0x"` and still the same error is showing up.

I'm using g++ 4.3.3 because the software requires to do so.

Anyone any idea how to approach this?

Comment: How can I remove it because I can't find it anywhere on the makefile.unix

Comment: out of curiosity: "I'm using g++ 4.3.3 because the software requires to do so." is this really the case? Or do you just need C++03? Requiring a specific compiler version is a bit strange, while also any newer version can be configured to compile as C++03

Comment: The software requires the 4.3.3 version of gcc and that's why I'm using it but I can't fix the error I stated on the topic.

Comment: c++0x stands for C++11, try `CXXFLAGS=""`

Comment: It didn't work still the same error is showing up.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show your `makefile.unix`?  Does it contain any `include` directives?

Comment: Don't worry about gcc version, just try a newer version.